# Why do consecutive iterates need to be “close” in matrix secant methods?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, secant

I know the vague idea about how matrix secant methods work:  The essence of the method is still using Newton’s method to do the updates, and thus it is doing root finding on $f(x)$ and updating the the $x_k$ iterates by this:

$$x_{k+1} = x_k – J’(x_k)^{-1} J(x_k)$$, where $J(x_k)$ is the jacobian of $f(x)$

then of course the secant method is striving to do what newton’s method does, with two modifications:

1) we are trying to find the roots of the gradient, $g(x) = \nabla f(x) = 0 $

2) we take a secant approximation of the Jacobian instead of the jacobian itself:  $M_k (x_{k+1} – x_k) = g(x_{k+1}) – g(x_k)$

Then, the next idea of the matrix secant methods is that consecutive iterates on the approximation of $M_k$ be close to each other, i.e. minimize $ ||M_k – M_{k+1} || $.

For example, in Nocedal and Wright, we have the sentence: “…and a requirement that the difference between successive approximations have low rank.”  Why is it that we want consecutive iterates of the secant methods to be “close” to each other in this sense?

Comment: Furthermore, why do we require that the updates to the matrix preserve symmetry and positive definiteness?

Comment: I've found this resource: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/408/lectures/L11-Matrix-Secant-Methods.pdf, which describes on slide 15, that the iterates should be close to each other because "we assume that..$B_k$ becomes a better approximation..".   But, how do we know that our consecutive iterates get closer and closer each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked a lot of questions, and I will attempt to provide an "answer" - the quotes are there since to the best of my knowledge there is no formal proof for the fact that these methods work better than the gradient method, despite their excellent performance in practice.

So first, let's look at (the pure) Newton's method for *minimization* - we find a descent direction $d_k$ by solving the system $\nabla^2 f(x_k) d_k = -\nabla f(x_k)$, and then compute
$$
x_{k+1} = x_k + d_k = x_k - [\nabla^2 f(x_k)]^{-1} \nabla f(x_k).
$$

First, observe that $d_k$ is indeed a descent direction if and only if $\nabla^2 f(x_k)$ is *positive definite*. Since $M_k$ attempts to imitate the Hessian, it should also be positive definite. This answers your second question (in the comments).

To answer the rest, I will need to look from another perspective. Observe, that Newton's method is equivalent to
$$
x_{k+1} = \operatorname*{argmin}_x \{ f(x_k) + \nabla f(x_k)^T (x - x_k) + \frac{1}{2} (x - x_k)^T \nabla^2 f(x_k)(x - x_k)  \}
$$
Indeed, when $\nabla^2 f(x_k)$ is positive definite the function inside the braces is convex, and if you compare its gradient w.r.t $x$ to zero, you obtain the Newton update. What is inside the braces is the 2nd order Taylor approximation. So Newton's method essentially assumes that the 2nd order Taylor approximation is a good approximation for the function, which we can minimize instead of minimizing the function itself.

Remember that the error term in the 2nd order approximation includes the 3rd derivatives. If they are small, the approximation is good. Thus, Newton's method works well when the 2nd derivative changes 'slowly' in some sense. And indeed, there are theorems which rely on this slowness to formally prove its convergence: either assume that $\nabla^2 f$ is Lipschitz continuous, or assume that $f$ is self-concordant.

This analysis attempts to intuitively answer your first question - why do we require consecutive $M_k$ to be close to each other - it is to imitate the behavior of the Hessian of such 'good' functions where the Hessian changes slowly.

Comment: So if we wanted to relax the assumption that the 2nd order Taylor approximation is a good approximation for the function, then we might not need the positive definiteness requirement?  otherwise, I understand why positive definiteness is required, thanks!  But why is symmetry required?

Comment: And, about the consecutive iterates being close to each other – it has nothing to do with how good our past estimates of the Hessian were?  I thought for sure it had something to do with the fact that we are accumulating information as the algorithm proceeds (since it is self-correcting), but seems like you are not including that in the explanation.

Comment: No. If you want to relax the assumption that the 2nd order Taylor approximation is good, you might not need the assumption that the Hessian changes slowly - that is, you might not need the assumption that consecutive Hessian approximations are close to each other.

The positive definiteness is needed so that the direction $d_k$ is a descent direction. Otherwise, the 2nd order Taylor approximation is *unbounded*, and its minimum cannot be attained (it is $-\infty$).

Symmetry, of course, is needed since the real Hessian is symmetric. And we are trying to immitate it.

Comment: okay, @Alex so the positive definiteness relates to finding a descent direction, whereas the closeness requirement relates to assuming the second order TS expansion is accurate. By the positive definiteness requirement, we are guaranteeing that $d_k$ is a direction of descent with respect to our *approximated hessian* – I agree - but we don’t know if it is a direction of descent to the *original function*, right?        Furthermore, the 2nd order Taylor approximation *might* be unbounded, but not necessarly.  if it is indefinite then it can be bounded below.

Comment: Positive definiteness ensures descent without being related to the Hessian at all. For any positive definite matrix $H$, the vector $d_k = -H \nabla f(x_k)$ is a descent direction at $f(x_k)$. This is because of a fundamental propertie of directional derivatives for differentiable functions: $f'(x; d) = \nabla f(x)^T d$.  In our case, $f'(x_k; -H \nabla f(x_k)) = -\nabla f(x)^T H \nabla f(x_k) < 0$. Since the directional derivative is negative, we get a descent direction.